# Multiplayer game crash only iPad

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, cross-platform, google-play-services, multiplayer

I am developing a multiplayer cross platform game with Unity. I use google play game services. When i install to iPhone 6 everything works fine. Player can sign in and create a quick match but when i try it in iPad 2 the game crashes. How can i figure out this. I have 2 different google accounts for each device both google+ enabled. 
Here is my code.

```
private void StartMatchMaking() 
{
    PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.RealTime.CreateQuickGame (minimumOpponents, maximumOpponents, gameVariation, this);
}


public void SignInAndStartMPGame() {

    if (! PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.localUser.authenticated) 
    {
        PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) => {
            if (success) 
            {
                Debug.Log ("We're signed in! Welcome " + PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.localUser.userName);
                // We could start our game now
                StartMatchMaking();
            } 
            else 
            {
                Debug.Log ("Oh... we're not signed in.");
            }
        });
    } 
    else
    {
        Debug.Log ("You're already signed in.");
        // We could also start our game now
        StartMatchMaking();
    }
}
```

Console messages:

DEBUG: Populating User.
DEBUG: Maybe finish for User
DEBUG: Auth finished. Proceeding.
DEBUG: Invoking Callbacks: System.Action`1[System.Boolean]
DEBUG: Invoking user callback on game thread
We're signed in! Welcome Player

DEBUG: Entering state: BeforeRoomCreateStartedState
DEBUG: BeforeRoomCreateStartedState.OnStateEntered: Defaulting to no-op.
DEBUG: QuickGame: Setting MinPlayersToStart = 1
DEBUG: OnData Callback has addr: 27
DEBUG: BeforeRoomCreateStartedState.IsNonPreemptable: Is preemptable by default.
DEBUG: Entering state: RoomCreationPendingState
DEBUG: RoomCreationPendingState.OnStateEntered: Defaulting to no-op.

INFO: Connect with retry.getRetryAuthToken(): 1
INFO: Token expired.  Refreshing.
Trying to refresh token; old token is: 
VERBOSE: Kicking off refresh request to main thread now.
VERBOSE: Waiting for refresh request to return now.
Auth updated!  ... maybe.  New token is: ya29.PAIpxX-k4s7tN562YGmekCZW3TJ
VERBOSE: Refresh request returned.
Token refresh success!
VERBOSE: Different token!  Refresh successful!
INFO: Trying to connect with returned auth token.

CRASHES!

Comment: can you add some logging to see if there are any errors that you are not aware of that are happening on the `IPad2`  can you also step through the code and see if you can spot / pinpoint where it's crashing..?

Comment: I edit console log messages is it helpful for you to give an answer @MethodMan